# invalid value encountered in double_scalars and UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision is ill-defined

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

After running this code

```
matthews_corrcoef(test_labels, y_test_pred)*100
```

I encountered this error

```
 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py:900: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  mcc = cov_ytyp / np.sqrt(cov_ytyt * cov_ypyp)
0.0
```

And for precision score

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
sklearn.metrics.precision_score(test_labels, y_test_pred, pos_label= 1)*100
```

Got another error

```
 usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py:1272: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))
0.0
```

To solve this problem, I tried to remove NAN and infinite value from training and test data with this code

```
te_fin = np.nan_to_num(te_fin)
```

But still, the problem persisting and the model runtime is very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second message is a warning, which is raised by the sklearn.metrics.precision_score function. To get rid of the warning you have to explicitly specify the desired behaviour via the 'zero_divison' argument. Note that the precision is calculated using the formula precision = Tp / (Tp + Fp). The warning tells you that a division by zero is being performed, which is an invalid operation. This means that your predicted values contain no positive label and all labels are predicted as negative.

The first warning is raised for the same reason but the function doesn't offer an argument to specify what to do in case of a zero division. You might have to check for the values yourself before calling the function to avoid the warning.